# Wit ai based node.js code on running with forever command throws error

Tags: node.js, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, wit.ai

I am trying to develop a **facebook messenger bot** application with the use of **wit.ai** framework. The application runs fine when i run my **node.js** code with command

> node app.js

But when i try to run it with the use of forever command like below i am getting the following error in wit library file.

> forever -o out.log -e err.log start app.js

string_decoder.js:66
  var buflen = buffer.length;
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

at StringDecoder.write (string_decoder.js:66:22)
at Interface._normalWrite (readline.js:319:30)
at Interface.write (readline.js:310:49)
at message.converse.makeActionCallback.runActions.interactive.rl.on [as 
interactive] (/home/user/example/lib/wit.js:289:13)
at Object. (/home/user/example/app.js:540:8)                              at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this which was suggested by someone else in github. In wit.js line 300 replace

> this.rl.write(null, {ctrl: true, name: 'e'});

with

> this.rl.write( '', {ctrl: true, name: 'e'});